# Spark HashPartitioner Unexpected Partitioning

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am using `HashPartioner` but getting an unexpected result.
I am using 3 different String as keys, and giving partition parameter as 3, so I expect 3 partitions.

```scala
val cars = Array("Honda", "Toyota", "Kia")

val carnamePrice = sc.parallelize(for {
 x <- cars
 y <- Array(100,200,300)
} yield (x, y), 8)
val rddEachCar = carnamePrice.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(3))
val mapped =   rddEachCar.mapPartitionsWithIndex{
                (index, iterator) => {
                   println("Called in Partition -> " + index)
                   val myList = iterator.toList

                   myList.map(x => x + " -> " + index).iterator
                }
             }
mapped.take(10)
```

The result is below. It gives only 2 partitions. I checked hash codes for String
(69909220 75427 -1783892706). What could be problem here? Probably I misunderstood partitioning algorithm.

```scala
Array[String] = Array((Toyota,100) -> 0, (Toyota,200) -> 0, (Toyota,300) -> 0, (Honda,100) -> 1, (Honda,200) -> 1, (Honda,300) -> 1, (Kia,100) -> 1, (Kia,200) -> 1, (Kia,300) -> 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing strange going on here. [`Utils.nonNegativeMod`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4e27578faa67c7a71a9b938aafbaf79bdbf36831/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L1663-L1666), which is used by `HashPartitioner` is implemented as follows:

```scala
def nonNegativeMod(x: Int, mod: Int): Int = {
  val rawMod = x % mod
  rawMod + (if (rawMod < 0) mod else 0)
}
```

With 3 partitions the key distribution is defined as shown below:

```scala
for { car <- Seq("Honda", "Toyota", "Kia") } 
  yield (car -> nonNegativeMod(car.hashCode, 3))
```

```
Seq[(String, Int)] = List((Honda,1), (Toyota,0), (Kia,1))
```

which is exactly what you get in your case. In other words, lack of direct hash collision doesn't guarantee lack of collision modulo an arbitrary number.