# how to balance the load while using hash partition-er?

Tags: apache-spark, hash, partitioning

In  apache spark ->  By using the Hash partition-er ,  I believe the keys with same hash value will go on to same node? what if most of the keys goes on to same partition-er and how to balance the data on multiple worker node in such scenarios . please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc says .. [A Partitioner that implements hash-based partitioning using Java's `Object.hashCode`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/HashPartitioner.html)

**Yes**. you are right. So if distribution of keys are not uniform you can end up in situations when part of your cluster is idle. [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424396/how-does-hashpartitioner-work)

***Its your responsibility to ensure that keys are uniformly distributed across.(that means hashcode should not be same)***

For that you need better understanding of `HashPartitioner` and what it does internally.

Note : Hash code of the key will just be the key itself. The `HashPartitioner` will mod it with the number of total partitions. i.e hashcode Mod with totnumpartions.

Below [Util](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4e27578faa67c7a71a9b938aafbaf79bdbf36831/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L1663-L1666) class method is used for that purpose by `HashPartitioner`

```
def nonNegativeMod(x: Int, mod: Int): Int = {
  val rawMod = x % mod
  rawMod + (if (rawMod < 0) mod else 0)
}
```

- for better understanding look at perfect example - [spark-hashpartitioner-unexpected-partioning   - answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41785089/647053) by @user6910411

Comment: So you mean to say we need to write our own custom partition-er to split the keys among all the partitions we have ?

Comment: No need to write custom partioner. Hashcode of keys should be uniform. For multiple keys hash code should not be same.